# How does standardization affect naive bays classifer

Tags: naivebayes, standardized

Can anyone explain how standardization of data can increase the performace of a gaussian naive bayes classifier? i standardized the data im using and some how it increased the accuracy. as far as i know it shouldnt since GNB classifies a label with the MAP rule. anyone know how it can affect the classifier?

Comment: ive seen many sources online where it does give an example where standardization does increase performance but ive never seen any explain as to why it does

Comment: Ive found the answer. If the data you are using has a very high variance, the assumed normal distribution be spread out over a large range of values wihich will decrease the value of the probability density. When you are using many parameter with high values, the joint probability will be very small and can lead to imprecision due to the limit of preciosion of the computer (number of decimal being used in calculation). Standardizing the data will make the probability have a value not to small nor too big for calculation